# Connecting Tableau to Heroku Follower Database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, tableau-api

Have created a follower database for a Heroku Postgres DB.  I am able to connect to the follower DB by using pgAdmin, no problem.

When I try to connect with Tableau 8.2 Postgres connector using the same credentials, I get "no pg_hba.conf entry for host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, user yyyyyyyy, database zzzzzzzz, SSL Off".

As an alternative I tried the Amazon Redshift connector with the same credentials and it works, except for full drill through to underlying data errors out ("Syntax error at or near 7500") or some other line number.

Does anyone know a way to connect to Heroku Follower database with Tableau 8.2 that enables drill through (view underlying data)?

Have you been able to get the Postgres connector to work?

Is there a way to get the Amazon Redshift (or other) connector to work with drill through capabilities?

Comment: "SSL Off" <-- You should connect using SSL.